# When a task fails on a server, run a different task on only that server

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have a capistrano task that restarts a background job on multiple servers. Sometimes, that job will have died on a server, and so the restart command will fail because the job isn't running. In this case I'd like to call my start task (rather than the restart task). Here's my attempt:

```
namespace :job do
  desc "Restart the job"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    output = nil
    begin
      run "sudo restart myjob DEPLOY=true NAME='myjob1'" do |channel, stream, data|
        output = data
      end
    rescue Capistrano::CommandError => error
      if output.match("restart: Unknown instance: myjob")
        puts "****** WARNING ***** job was not running -- starting it"
        start
      else
        puts "some other unknown error, die"
        raise error
      end
    end
  end

  desc "Start the job"
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "sudo start myjob DEPLOY=true NAME='myjob1'"
  end
end
```

The problem with what I've done above, is that when I call "start", it will run the start task on all servers, when I only want it to run on the server that died. Maybe I can pass the host to the start command somehow? Haven't been able to find how tho. Cheers.

Comment: The `task`accepts hosts parameter. Example : `task :start, :hosts => ["host1", "host2"]` You can add the failed hosts to an array and then run `start unless failed_hosts.empty?`

Comment: but then I would need to define my list of failed_hosts when i declare the task rather than when i run the task, and i don't know which ones fail yet. unless i'm misunderstanding. if i were to call ```start(:hosts => failed_hosts)```, how do i access that variable in the start task?

Comment: OK I found [how to pass variables across tasks](http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/548), and I'm then passing that to ```run``` i.e. ```run "blah", :hosts => failed_hosts```. thanks